# OS Looping over files is printing out twice

Tags: python

The following code works as intended, looping over files in my folder and performing some read write actions.

The files are updated correctly too.

Issue is with the print out. It ends up printing the same set of results twice in console. Why?

```
import os
import csv

root_directory = '.'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            initial = {}
            repeated = set()
            my_file = file
            sample = my_file[:2]
            output_file = '{}_result.txt'.format(sample.lower())

            with open(my_file, mode='r') as in_file, \
                    open(output_file, mode='w') as out_file:
                next(in_file)
                reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter="\t")
                for i, line in enumerate(reader):
                    row = line[0].split(',')

                    if row[1] in initial:
                        shouldAdd = initial[row[1]] != row[2]
                        if shouldAdd:
                            repeated.add(row[1])
                            out_file.write('{}\n'.format(row[1])) # writing to file here no issues, no duplicates
                    else:
                        initial[row[1]] = row[2]

            #Issue is here. Why printing twice
            print('Total repeats for {} sample: {}'.format(sample, len(repeated)))
```

Prints out as follows:

```
Total repeats for AA sample: 123
Total repeats for BB sample: 45
Total repeats for AA sample: 123
Total repeats for BB sample: 45
```

Got 4 lines above. It should have stopped after line 2.

Comment: You have files with the same name in different subdirectories. You're only using the name, not the directory.

Comment: To validate @Barmar's comment change your print to `print('Total repeats for {} sample: {}'.format(sample, len(repeated)), subdir)`

Comment: @Barmar was right. I moved out a subdir which had identical files. Was under the impression it would only loop top level and not loiter into sub directories.

Comment: If you only want to loop one directory, use `os.listdir()`. What did you think the `subdirs` return values were for if it didn't go into subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the `subdir` variable. The same filename exists in a subdirectory, but you're processing the file in the root directory twice. You need to use `os.path.join(subdir, file)` to get the full pathname of the file.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            fullname = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            initial = {}
            repeated = set()
            my_file = file
            sample = my_file[:2]
            output_file = os.path.join(subdir, '{}_result.txt'.format(sample.lower()))

            with open(fullname, mode='r') as in_file, \
                    open(output_file, mode='w') as out_file:
                next(in_file)
                reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter="\t")
                for i, line in enumerate(reader):
                    row = line[0].split(',')

                    if row[1] in initial:
                        shouldAdd = initial[row[1]] != row[2]
                        if shouldAdd:
                            repeated.add(row[1])
                            out_file.write('{}\n'.format(row[1])) # writing to file here no issues, no duplicates
                    else:
                        initial[row[1]] = row[2]

            #Issue is here. Why printing twice
            print('Total repeats for {}/{} sample: {}'.format(subdir, sample, len(repeated)))
```